computing the best confusion matrix
I have a set of score for a disease like this:
phenotype   score
pathogenic  -1.24
pathogenic  -1.14
pathogenic  -0.97
pathogenic  -0.72
pathogenic  -0.69
pathogenic  -0.67
benign  -0.59
pathogenic  -0.57
pathogenic  -0.52
pathogenic  -0.46
pathogenic  -0.33
pathogenic  -0.30
benign  -0.27
benign  -0.16
benign  -0.12
benign  -0.10
benign  -0.09
pathogenic  -0.06
benign  -0.05
benign  -0.03
benign  -0.03
benign  -0.02
benign  -0.005
benign  0.002
benign  0.015
pathogenic  0.04
benign  0.06
benign  0.06
benign  0.06
benign  0.07
benign  0.09
benign  0.16
benign  0.18
benign  0.22

I want to find the best score that separates pathogenic from benign using confusion matrix. Visual looking at the box plots hints that the score could be around -0.27 but I want to have a script for large datasets. Basically the script should do a loop, choose a score, and see what is the precision and FDR rate, repeating until it finds min and max scores such that going beyond those will reduce accuracy. min and max scores sometimes could be exact same score. Is there any python package for doing this? Thanks

sounds like you want to use sklearn's confusion_matrix
